# On delete confirmation window does not appears in php

Tags: php, javascript

Please tell where I am wrong so that I can correct it? Its not giving error it should show confirmation window before it deletes record but it directly deletes record

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation');
    var confirmIt = function (e) {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) e.preventDefault();
    };
    for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
    }
</script>
```

Link for delete:

```
<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?action=delete&id=$id' class='confirmation'> Delete</a>
```

delete function:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && trim($_GET['action'])=="delete")
{
$del="delete from contacts where id='".$_GET['id']."'";

mysql_query($del) or die(mysql_error());
header("Location: mainpage.php");
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: stop using `mysql_query` . Use MySQLi / PDO instead. Plus, remember to call `exit();` after `header('Location: $url');`

Comment: Do you check $_GET['id'] at all?

Comment: *sidenote:* this code is vulnerable to attack. As it is a `$_GET`, I can substitute any value into the `$id`, which can remove ALL your records in your DB in a for-loop.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Your post may be misleading. It's not because it's `$_GET` really. `$_POST` for example would be just as vulnerable. All input needs to be sanitized.

Comment: you have to write js at the bottom ,you are assigning the click when the dom is not yet loaded i suppose

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want the link to activate when you click on it, the onclick must return false.